# What does "certificate is valid for 10.96.0.1, 10.198.74.71, not 127.0.0.1" mean?

Tags: certificate, localhost, argo-workflows

What does this error mean?  I have Argo workflows working on my development computer, but when I deploy it, this is what I see. Where do I need to start reading to fix it?

ERROR

```
Post https://127.0.0.1:6443/apis/argoproj.io/v1alpha1/namespaces/argo/workflows: x509: certificate is valid for 10.96.0.1, 10.198.74.71, not 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes across a strange error like this, it is (again) an RBAC problem. To fix this error, I updated my kubeconfig to reflect the current clusters and roles.